# How to concatenate data in XSL and insert "/" each display

Tags: xml, xslt

i want to combine using for-each and insert "/" each display this is example of Full XML:

```
<root>
<level1>
    <level2 name="ex1">
        <title>something1</title>
        <country>
          <value>Malaysia</value>
          <value>Singapore</value>
          <value>Brunei</value>
          <value>Japan</value>
          <value>China</value>
      </country>
    </level2>

    <level2 name="ex2">
        <title>something2</title>
        <country>
          <value>Brunei</value>
          <value>Japan</value>
          <value>China</value>
      </country>
    </level2>

</level1>
</root>
```

i have try concat country with "/" (im focusing straight to for-each):

```
<xsl:for-each select="//level2">

    Name : <xsl:value-of select="@name" /> <br />
    Title : <xsl:value-of select="title" /> <br />
    Country : <xsl:value-of select="concat(country, '/')" /> <br />
    </br>

 </xsl:for-each>
```

but it is display :

```
Name : ex1
Title : something1
Country : Malaysia Singapore Brunei Japan China /

Name : ex2
Title : something2
Country : Brunei Japan China /
```

**However i want it to display like this :**

```
name : ex1
Title : something1
Country : Malaysia/Singapore/Brunei/Japan/China

name : ex2
Title : something2
Country : Brunei/Japan/China
```

Comment: Please show the code attempt you've already made

Comment: i have edited my question with code i hv made

Comment: @DanielHaley look at element example got attribute `name` verson 1.0

Comment: @DanielHaley sorry im 1st time posting question, i have edit and hope u understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, you will need to process each `country/value` individually and check the position to see if a `/` should be output.

Try changing your `xsl:for-each` to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//level2">

  Name : <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
  Title : <xsl:value-of select="title" />
  Country : <xsl:for-each select="country/value">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">/</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively, instead of using `xsl:for-each` (pull processing), you could use `xsl:apply-templates` (push processing)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//level2"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="level2">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;&#xA;Name : </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;Title : </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="country">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;Country : </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="value"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
      <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or a combination of both pull/push...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">    
    <xsl:for-each select="//level2">

      Name : <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
      Title : <xsl:value-of select="title" />
      Country : <xsl:apply-templates select="country/value"/>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">/</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```